# Why is datetime returning today's date instead of the input date?

Tags: php, datetime

```
<?php
// Convert MMDDYY to YYYY-MM-DD date format to be INSERTed
// into MySQL TABLE.
// If it can't convert the data because of an error, it returns 0000-00-00.
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

function date_convert($date_input) {
    try {
    $date = new DateTime($date_input);
    $date_processed = $date->format('Y-m-d'); 
    } catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Wrong date format $date_input" . "\n";
    $date_processed = "0000-00-00";
}
    return $date_processed;
}

// MMDDYY (January 1, 2000)
$TRANSACTION_DATE_MMDDYY_raw = "010100";
echo date_convert($TRANSACTION_DATE_MMDDYY_raw) . "\n";
?>
```

Output:
    2013-06-28

I'm expecting it to return 2000-01-01, but it's returning today's date. What am I missing? How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I posted my answer just for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373007/how-to-check-for-a-failed-datetime-in-php/17373200#17373200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has no way to know your date is formated like MMDDYY. There are two ways to solve this:

- use one of the '[valid formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)'. You can eather change your input value, or parse it to a valid format with some string functions or a regex.
- use the static [createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method that comes with the DateTime class.

As I presume changing the input is not an option, and parsing the input seems a bit far fetched, using the second method seems the most appropriate here, and would result in changing this:

```
$date = new DateTime($date_input);
```

into this:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('mdy', $date_input);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the `createFromFormat` method. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Is createFromFormat allowing to specify the input format and if it doesn't match it fails?

Comment: `createFromFormat` tells the `DateTime` class which format to expect and parse. Your format, `MMDDYY` would be `DateTime::createFromFormat("mdy", $date_input);` would be your best solution for creating the `$date` object in your `date_convert` function.

Comment: Also, according to the docs (http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), `createFromFormat` will indeed return `FALSE` if some error occurs, instead of a valid `DateTime` instance.

Comment: ^ +1. Good point; you'll need to rewrite your `date_convert` function a little differently and do a type check.. ex: `if(false === $date) { bad date } else { do something }`

Answer (score -1):

The format you specified can't be converted/isnt recognized to be a proper format. Try `'2000-01-01'`